# MS Project Delete Custom Fields Dialog Opening After Running Code

Tags: vba, vsto, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013, ms-project-server-2016

I have tool that's part of a VSTO add-in for MS Project that clears data out of an MS Project file that the user chooses. It uses methods such as  `Application.CustomFieldDelete()`, `Application.CustomFieldPropertiesEx()`, `Application.BaselineClear()`,  `Application.SetTaskFieldByID()`, `ActiveProject.Views[x].Delete()`, `ActiveProject.TaskTables[x].Delete()`, `Task.SetField()`  etc...

[image: Sanitizer]

After the tool runs, when I try to insert a column in the Gantt Table, MS Project opens this dialog:

[image: Delete Custom Fields Dialog]

Project forces me to delete a text field to insert any column even though, as you can see, not every text field has a custom name applied. In fact, after I run the tool with the setup from the above image, only 4 Text fields have a custom name still applied, the rest get the `Application.CustomFieldDelete()` method done to them.

I've had this problem occur in the past with VBA macros I had created, but I was never sure what exactly caused it. What would cause Project to do this, and how can I avoid it?